# Are there applications for generating human-friendly but secure passwords?

Tags: security, passwords, password-generation

I'm using [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) for storing my passwords for various sites, because [you're more vulnerable than you think](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001263.html) if you use the same password on multiple sites (especially if it is short enough to be reversed through rainbow tables.)

What I'm looking for now is a way to create good rememberable/memoable (what's the word?) passwords that I can use for KeePass itself and for other purposes where I don't want the passwords to be stored anywhere but in my head (like my internet bank.)

Does anyone know of any good generators? They don't necessarily have to be easy to remember mentally; as long as they're generated to be fluently written on the keyboard, they should be easy enough to learn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't generate one, make your own memorable one!

[This](http://www.passwordmeter.com/) site will allow you to test it's strength against multiple criteria.

Comment: That's cool how they don't explicitly check for dictionary words but any word is automatically considered weak as any part of a password since it contains consecutive letters.

Comment: That's a nice site, I will bookmark it =)

Comment: It only accepts 16 letter passwords, making it unable to judge any of my passphrases...

Comment: Hmm and it often drops to 0% if you go to the max length just by repeating a single character...  doesn't really feel good.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I would do with a password that needs to be strong: type it into a random website. Yeah, I realize that the app is javascript and probably runs all client-side, but I would never recommend a site like that to anybody who does not know much about software/computes - the chance that somebody is recording your password is too high. And they got your IP-address as well.

Comment: If you'd care to read the bottom of the page, it's all freely available under GNU GPL. browse the source yourself.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what platform you're on, but Mac OS X has a tool like this built into the Accounts settings:

[image]

It can also estimate how strong any password is, and it has lots of Type and Length options.

As for other platforms, or generic things, a bit of Googling has led me to these:

- http://www.goodpassword.com/
- http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/

And more.

Comment: You did *what* with *how* many bricks?

Answer (score 3):

There's lots of generators for this kind of thing, but really there's a couple methods I use to come up with something like this - master passwords.

Combine several old passwords. You probably have muscle memory from typing them, the hardest part is remembering the order :-).

Write a perl, shell, ruby, etc one-liner script. Something like:

```
perl -e '/Password/ and print;'
cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '/root/ {print $2}'
```

Write a sentence and use the first letter of each word, and any punctuation used. For example, the previous sentence would be "`Wasautfloew,aapu.`" - including the period.

Finally, remember that a long password of few character classes (ie all lower case) is stronger than a short password with multiple character classes (ie lower case, numbers, special characters). So "`asdoihaoeihwoeihfaoihbzoihzsdofihasodfihafz`" is stronger than "`0mgWtf$!`".

Comment: Thanks for the tips =) That's something I'm after, something that easily sticks in "muscle memory" because your fingers remember complex passwords way better than your brain =) I just figured it must be easier to learn something that is efficient for your fingers to type, so I was after some application that specifically generated passwords efficient to write on a QWERTY keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that a human friendly password is more succeptable to a dictionary attack. I'd try to creat as strong and secure a password as you can remember.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not after something like "cheesesandwich123", but something that is specifically generated to be quick and easy to type while still being an unguessable mix of alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative take  -- [**SuperGenPass**](http://supergenpass.com/).
Saw it at the [Google OS tips blog](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/03/supergenpass-simple-password-generator.html).

Try something like, this blog entry: [**A password generator I can remember**](http://calliopesounds.blogspot.com/2009/05/password-generator-i-can-remember.html)

**I would never trust an online system to generate my password** though.
([**SuperGenPass mobile**](http://supergenpass.com/mobile/) for example).

I liked `John`s [**PasswordMeter**](http://www.passwordmeter.com/) reference a lot (+1 to him for that).

Answer (score 0):

I use [Password Maker](http://passwordmaker.org/) (or the same thing with lots of the fields hidden for simplicity: [Password Maker Lite](http://www.updike.org/pml/) ).  It only runs on JavaScript on your machine so you aren't storing or transmitting anything.

Answer (score 0):

On most Linux machines, you can find a small binary called [pwgen](http://packages.debian.org/sv/lenny/pwgen) which generates a whole bunch of easy-to-remember passwords. The recommended password length is 12 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a random book out of your bookshelf. Open the book at a random page and select a random sentence.

Note the first letter of every word and add them up. That's your new password. Of course, the sentence should be long enough to provide you 12+ characters.

Sentences are easy to remember. You can also additionally add a number at the end or beginning every time to add a further layer of obscurity.

Answer (score 0):

I always use pass-phrases - the longer the better... Going above 14-16 characters is the first sweet spot to aim for and the character variation can suffer a hit if it means it's longer. This is easily done and remembered with a regular sentence like "Get things done today again!" or "Damn I'm good at this!".

A bonus is that most computer users can type regular sentences much faster and more accurately which lowers the risk of someone spotting what you're typing.

Obviously, passwords need to be changed on a regular basis, or they're near useless.

Answer (score 0):

[Keepassx](http://www.keepassx.org/) has a pronounceable password generator built into it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good website with a few interesting options for password generation, strength testers etc.

It isn't flawed terribly like some of the major websites that people are currently using for password generation and testing.

http://www.kevtech-apps.com/